# Getting 403 response when trying to change meta data of objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I'm the owner of the account and project.
I login using the google cloud sdk and try the following command:

```
gsutils -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" gs//bucket/**/*.*
```

I get the following error for some of the files:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 <owner@email.com> does not have storage.objects.update access to <filePath>
```

Most of the files are updated, but some are not. Because I have a lot of files, if 10% are not updated, that means a few gigs of data is not updated.

Any idea why this happens with an owner account and how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden on GCS using owner account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719495/accessdeniedexception-403-forbidden-on-gcs-using-owner-account)

Answer (score 1):

If the Access Control on your bucket is set to Uniform you need to add permissions to it even if you are project owner.

For example:

I have a test file in a bucket and when I want to access it I get an access required popup.

I gave to my Owner account in the permissions tab of the bucket "Storage Object Admin" and now I can access it freely.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#project-level_roles_vs_bucket-level_roles) you have more info about Project Level Roles vs Bucket Level Roles.

Let me know.