# Access Denied Exception message when pulling down files from google bucket

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I have been running a batch file to pull files from google bucket which was created by someone and had been working in the past, however, now I'm getting an error message stating 
"ACCESS DENIED EXCEPTION:403 tim@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.list access to dcct_-dcm_account870"
What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: What does this have to do with CMD - *Command Prompt (executable name cmd.exe) is the Microsoft supplied command line interpreter on OS/2, Windows CE, and all Windows operating systems (including Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10, Windows Server 2003, Server 2008, Server 2012, and Server 2016).* PLUS your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution to this issue. 
I notice that ****@gmail.com have left  the company and i have to reconfigure the gsutil to give access to myself using the link below for previous answer

[gsutil cors set command returns 403 AccessDeniedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190365/gsutil-cors-set-command-returns-403-accessdeniedexception)